# MVC @Html.Partial - Two Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-mvc

I am trying to use partial view in a view.  The first view requires a Model while the partial view requires IEnumerable of the same model.  I get the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyVDC.Models.LogBook', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyVDC.Models.LogBook]'.
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(string phn)
    {
        phn = MySession.Current.PHN;
        ViewBag.PHN = MySession.Current.PHN;
        LogBook logBook = new LogBook();
        try
        {
            logBook = db.LogBooks.Where(c => c.PHN == phn).OrderByDescending(x => x.Day).First();
        }
        catch
        {
            logBook.Day = DateTime.Now.Date;
            logBook.PHN = phn;
        }
        return View(logBook);
    }
```

Second action for the partial view:

```
 public ActionResult Grid()
        {
            string phn = MySession.Current.PHN;
            return View(db.LogBooks.ToList().Where(c => c.PHN == phn));
        }
```

The first view:

```
@model MyVDC.Models.LogBook
@{

}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <input type="hidden" name="PHN" id="PHN" value="@ViewBag.PHN" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>LogBook</legend>
        @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
            .Name("Day")

    )
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Start New Logbook" class="t-button" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
</div>
     @Html.Partial("Grid")
```

The second view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyVDC.Models.LogBook>

@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(o => o.Day).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Grid", "LogBook"))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
)
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.  Solve, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, by using ViewData as follows:
In the controller:

```
   ViewData["Log"] = db.LogBooks.ToList().Where(c => c.PHN == phn);
```

In the View:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid((IEnumerable<MyVDC.Models.LogBook>)ViewData["Log"])
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `Html.Render` is that the types associated with the two views need to be the same. You can use `Html.RenderAction` instead of `Html.Render`. When you use this approach, the types associated with the views don't matter. You'll want something like this:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Grid"); }
```